# What WinForm Control To Bind List(Of T)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop, presentation-layer

I have been working on keeping things object oriented for my project. Currently, I'm using a .DLL which supplies all of the app's classes to the WinForms project acting as the presentation layer.

My .DLL will, for example, return a SortableBindingList(Of T) to code in a form. The SortableBindingList(Of T) comes from [here](http://www.timvw.be/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt-take-two/). Let's assume a SortableBindingList(Of Product). Assuming that the .DLL's function `Services.Products.GetList()` returns a SortableBindingList(Of Product), I can easily do this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Services.Products.GetList()
```

Now, the DataGridView is properly populated with my list of Products. Fine. However, there is no .SelectedItem property which gives me back my object which was selected in the DataGridView:

```
' Doesn't exist!
Dim p As Product = DataGridView1.SelectedItem
' Need to make another DB call by getting the Product ID 
' from the proper Cell of the DataGridView ... yuck!
```

However, a ComboBox or a ListBox does in fact store and return my Product objects intact:

```
' Valid!
ComboBox1.DataSource = Services.Products.GetList()
Dim p as Product = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
```

Another however ... the ComboBox and ListBox do not show all of the fields of the Product object, only the value of the DisplayMember property.

Is there a nice control in VB.NET 2008 that I am just missing, which gives me the object oriented functionality that I want which will actually display an entire object's fields and also return that object back when selected by the user? I'm at a loss as to why there wouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the DataGridView's [SelectedRows property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx). You should be able to use that for what you're describing.

You use it to get the DataBoundItem then cast that to your original class. Let's say I had a list of Product objects bound, I would use something like:

```
Dim p As Product = CType(dataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem, Product)
MessageBox.Show(p.Name & " " & p.Price)
```

This works if the entire row is selected, otherwise you could get a null reference exception. In that case you could get the RowIndex of the currently selected cell via:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex
```

So all together this now looks like:

```
If dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0 Then
    Dim index as Integer = dataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex
    Dim p As Product = CType(dataGridView1.SelectedRows(index).DataBoundItem, Product)
    MessageBox.Show(p.Name & " " & p.Price)
End If
```

**EDIT:** updated to VB.NET

Comment: No, the .SelectedRows property returns an object of type DataGridViewRow, not the object that was originally bound to the DataGridView.

Comment: Updated answer. You use it to get to your data bound object then cast it appropriately.